# Python: Is there a way to suppress a function's plotting but keep the return?

Tags: python, plot

I have a function that generates an image, plots it in a pyplot figure and then returns the image as well. The function is long and it isn't entirely reasonable to find where exactly it actually does the plotting. Does anyone know of a way to simply suppress the plots but let the function run normally so I can get the returned images? This is in python 3.6 if that helps.

Comment: If the code is in your control, just break the function down into smaller functions that do less. This is the problem with carrying out many side effects in a single function: you're forced to cope with all effects it carries out. This could be avoided by having 1 function plot and another generate an image. Then the caller can decide what they want.

Comment: Would saving it to a file instead suffice?

Comment: The normal way to plot figures in pyplot is to use `pyplot.imshow(...)`. You could try to look for that call in the function and if it is there, remove it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The code is under my control but it is part of a package and I don't have the resources to dissect the contents (it spans many internal modules). Additionally, changing the underlying code in my installation doesn't solve the problem if my script is run from another person's machine which is why I'd ideally like to be able to do the suppression instead.

Comment: @PrestonM That could work. Is there a way to suppress the output but save the returns?

Comment: @JohanL See my response to Carcigenicate

Answer (score 1):

You could monkey-patch the function's namespace and replace the plotting function with a no-op function. 
Given

```
'''This is the to-be patched code, living in some module'''

def plot():
    print('Here is a plot: ##====>')

def do_the_plot():
    plot()
```

And then

```
'''Our new code, living some place else'''
def newplot():
    print('I wont do it!')

# The globals() will be replaced by the actual module names
globals()['plot'] = globals()['newplot']
do_the_plot()
```

prints `I wont do it!`

Comment: OP seems to be in control of the source code. In that case monkey patching seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely a solution at the abstraction level I need. Is there a way though to not have to go searching through the code for the plotting function? If not then I probably would go with this method

Comment: Well you need to know what code your want to monkey-patch ... Anyhow, as JohanL pointed at, if you can control the code, you may want to patch it on disk instead.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment above, the function you most likely want to remove/monkey patch is `pyplot.imshow(...)`. Try to override that one and have it do nothing. That is your best bet.